# Flickers UI in windows form application

Tags: c#

I am code for auto upload images to server. That images are come from folder and its name is show in my windows form UI if uploading complete then UI change in place of image name upload complete show.if new photos are come for upload again image name is show in the place of upload complete.
but when upload complete show is  flickers. How to solve it

```
public CustomNoteBox()
    {           
        InitializeComponent();
        // ImageNoteBox();
        _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RecallMetho(_cts.Token), _cts.Token);
    }
 private void RecallMetho(CancellationToken token)
    {
        XML TemperoryModelTemp = CP.XMlFileData();
        imagePath = TemperoryModelTemp.UploadImagePath;
        var newImagePath = OldUploading.OldUploadPath;

        if (imagePath != newImagePath)
        {
            ContentType.StopRecursionFuntionImageUpload = false;
            CP.UploadImage();
            ImageNameShow.CurImage = "";
        }
        while (true)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                break;
            }
            //if (WinOpenShow == true)
            //{
            //    Task.Delay(5000);
            //    WinOpenShow = false;
            //}
            if(ImageNameShow.CurImage != "Complete")
            {
                ImageNoteBox();
            }
            else
            {
                Imagecomplte();
            }

        }

    }
    private void ImageNoteBox()
    {
        XML TemperoryModelTemp = CP.XMlFileData();
        try
        {
            if (WinOpenShow == true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000); 
                WinOpenShow = false;
            }
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {

                //imageStatus.Text = ContentType.CurrentUploadedImage;
                headStatus.Text = " Uploading Photos";
                imagePath = TemperoryModelTemp.UploadImagePath;
                var newImagePath = OldUploading.OldUploadPath;
                panelComplete.Visible = false;
                pnlSelectPath.Text = imagePath;
                if (imagePath != newImagePath)
                {
                    ImageNameShow.CurImage = "";
                }
                //Changes Date 22Jan2020
                if (TemperoryModelTemp.IsCongratulationScreenOpen == "1")
                {
                    imageStatus.Text = " Status: Searching for Photos to upload from folder:";
                    imagePathlink.Visible = true;
                    imageName.Visible = false;
                    imagePathlink.Text = imagePath;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (ImageNameShow.CurImage == null)
                    {
                        imageStatus.Text = " Status: Searching for Photos to upload from folder:";
                        imagePathlink.Visible = true;
                        imageName.Visible = false;
                        imagePathlink.Text = imagePath;

                    }

                    else if (ImageNameShow.CurImage == "Complete")
                    {
                        panelComplete.Visible = true;
                        pnlSelectPath.Text = imagePath;
                        headStatus.Text = " Upload Complete";
                        UploadingStaus.Uplodingall = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (imagePath == newImagePath)
                        {
                            if (ImageNameShow.CurImage != "")
                            {
                                if (pathscreen == false)
                                {
                                    imageStatus.Text = " Status: Searching for Photos to upload from folder:";
                                    imagePathlink.Visible = true;
                                    imageName.Visible = false;
                                    imagePathlink.Text = imagePath;
                                    pathscreen = true;

                                    //Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(t => RecallMetho(_cts.Token));

                                    //System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
                                    //timer = new System.Threading.Timer((obj) =>
                                    //{
                                    //    RecallMetho(_cts.Token);
                                    //    timer.Dispose();
                                    //},
                                    //            null, 10000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

                                    WinOpenShow = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    imagePathlink.Visible = false;
                                    imageName.Visible = true;
                                    imageStatus.Text = " Status: Uploading photos to frame:" + '"' + CP.XMlFileData().Frame + '"';
                                    imageName.Text = ImageNameShow.CurImage;
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                imageStatus.Text = " Status: Searching for Photos to upload from folder:";
                                imagePathlink.Visible = true;
                                imageName.Visible = false;
                                imagePathlink.Text = imagePath;

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            imageStatus.Text = " Status: Searching for Photos to upload from folder:";
                            imagePathlink.Visible = true;
                            imageName.Visible = false;
                            imagePathlink.Text = imagePath;
                            OldUploading.OldUploadPath = imagePath;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            else
            {
                newWarningBox1.Dispose();
                //newWarningBox1 = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

    }
    private void Imagecomplte()
    {
        XML TemperoryModelTemp = CP.XMlFileData();
        try
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                //imageStatus.Text = ContentType.CurrentUploadedImage;
                headStatus.Text = " Uploading Photos";
                imagePath = TemperoryModelTemp.UploadImagePath;
                var newImagePath = OldUploading.OldUploadPath;
                panelComplete.Visible = false;
                pnlSelectPath.Text = imagePath;

                if (ImageNameShow.CurImage == "Complete")
                {
                    panelComplete.Visible = true;
                    pnlSelectPath.Text = imagePath;
                    headStatus.Text = " Upload Complete";
                    UploadingStaus.Uplodingall = true;
                }
            });
            else
            {
                newWarningBox1.Hide();
                //newWarningBox1 = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to decouple status message sending from UI updating. [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8) is the most primitive class that can split pushing status messages and UI update. Worker code can `Enqueue` status messages to the queue and some UI friendly thread can `TryPeek` new messages and update the UI on the form.

Another possibility is to use [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io) observer pattern implementation. The idea is the same: something produces the message and consumer processes them.

However turning UI control visibility on and off with high rate can cause `flickering`.
So you can try to avoid showing and hiding controls and use some status line (or multiline) label\readonly-textbox to put messages with `ImageNameShow.CurImage` content.